# Getting specific strings from cell in google sheet

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, replace, re2

I have a cell that i'm trying to get info out of.

This is the value of the cell C7 "(Liverpool-CAM) Firstname 'Nickname' Lastname"

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C7,"\'(.*?)\'"))
```

My Current formula is getting the nickname inbetween '', i would also like to add the Team name so in this case i would like the output to be Liverpool Nickname so i would like to add the string between "(" and "-".

It needs to have a contingency to only pull the string if there is a "(" infront of it since the names can include hyphens.

Having troubles with this if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(C7, "\((.+)\-.+'(.+)'.+", "$1 $2"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(C8, "\((.+)\-.+\).+'(.+)'.+", "$1 $2"))
```

[image]